# Prevent multiple equation numbers when using \allowdisplaybreak with align

Tags: cross-referencing, equations, align, labels

I have a very long equation of the following format

```
\begingroup
\allowdisplaybreaks
\begin{align}
a &= very long expression here\\
  + & another long expression here\\
  + & another long expression here
\end{align}
\endgroup
```

Now this equation is labelled thrice, once for each line. How do i make sure that the equation gets labelled only once?

Comment: Use `align*` and [make align* number the last equation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66759/make-align-number-the-last-equation).

Comment: Is using `multline` instead of `align` an option?

Comment: use `aligned` instead of `align`, and wrap that environment in `\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}`.  this will result in precisely one equation number.  requires `amsmath`, but then, so does `align`, so you are apparently already using that.  recommended reading: `texdoc amsldoc`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton But then there cannot be a page break between the lines, can there? (I assume he wishes that due the `\allowdisplaybreaks`.)

Comment: Another related question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42726/10679

Comment: Insert a `\notag` directive at the end of each line (just before the \\ line-break instruction) for every line you do *not* want to get numbered.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. -- `multline` doesn't align the parts in any useful way, although it does yield only one number and allow breaks.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. -- yes, you're correct. i didn't notice the `\allowdisplaybreaks`. so `\notag` on the lines that aren't to be numbered, or `align*` and an explicit `\tag` are the only feasible approaches. (however, having only one number on an equation that is split across pages is likely to be confusing, and thus not recommended.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Agreed, on both comments. (In hindsight, it wasn't a very good suggestion.)

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

Here is one solution. No need to use `\notag` on each line that should remain unnumbered if you use [this trick](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42728/21891); only insert `\numberthis` at the end of the equation.

---

[image]

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\numberthis[1][]{%
    \refstepcounter{equation}%
    \ifx#1\empty\else\label{eq:#1}\fi%
    \tag{\theequation}%
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]
filler text\\
filler text\\
filler text\\
filler text

{
\Large
\allowdisplaybreaks
\begin{align*}
a = b   &+ c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j\\
        &+ k + l + m + n + o + p + q +r \numberthis\\
        &+ s + t + u + v + w + x + y + z \numberthis[jubobs]
\end{align*}
}

See \ref{eq:jubobs}.
\end{document}
```