# Numbering of displayed math without using the equation environment

Tags: math-mode, numbering, amsmath, align

I know about `align` and `equation` environments, and tend to use them most of the time, but sometimes I like to have more flexibility within an array of equations, like better control on justification and horizontal spacing.
In that case, I use an `array` environment.
The only downside of this method (that I know of) is the fixed vertical spacing, but for equation arrays wherein every line has the same height, it is usually ok.

For reference, here is my code :

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand*{\defeq}{\vcentcolon=}
\newcommand*{\diff}{\mathrm{d}}

\newcommand*{\pd}[3][]{%
    \ensuremath%
    \frac{\partial^{#1}#2}{\partial #3^{#1}}
}

\newcommand*{\pdc}[4][]{%
    \ensuremath%
    \left(\pd[#1]{#2}{#3}\right)_{\!\!#4}
}

\newcommand{\td}[3][]{%
    \ensuremath%
    \frac{\diff^{#1}#2}{\diff #3^{#1}}
}

\newcommand{\earray}[3][2]{%
    \ensuremath%
    \everymath{\displaystyle}%
    \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{#1}%
    \begin{array}{#2}
        #3
    \end{array}
}


\begin{document}
\[
    \earray{r@{\;}l@{\;}ll}{
        \diff J^\pm 
            & \defeq \diff u\pm \frac{1}{C}\diff p 
            & =\left(F\pm\frac{1}{C}G\pdc{p}{e}{V}\right)\diff t 
            & \text{ along a path defined by } \td{\xi}{t}=\pm C,\\
        \diff S
            & \defeq \diff p + C^2 \diff V
            & =G\pdc{p}{e}{V} \diff t 
            & \text{ along a path defined by } \td{\xi}{t}=0
    }
\]

 \begin{align*}
    \diff J^\pm 
        & \defeq \diff u\pm \frac{1}{C}\diff p 
        & =\left(F\pm\frac{1}{C}G\pdc{p}{e}{V}\right)\diff t 
        & \text{ along a path defined by } \td{\xi}{t}=\pm C,\\
    \diff S
        & \defeq \diff p + C^2 \diff V
        & =G\pdc{p}{e}{V} \diff t 
        & \text{ along a path defined by } \td{\xi}{t}=0.
 \end{align*}
 \end{document}
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkZsD.png) is what the code produces.

So, my question is : is there a way to manually add tags inside displayed math ? Alternatively, is there a better way to proceed, or a better environment, for such cases ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Also, please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for people willing to help you solve your problem. Remove that one tedious hurdle; help them help you. In particular, your `\pd` command is nowhere defined.

Comment: [This](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112460/prevent-multiple-equation-numbers-when-using-allowdisplaybreak-with-align/112478#112478) may be of interest.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I would strongly advise against using `array` whenever possible. `amsmath` and `mathtools` usually offer enough building blocks for equations.

Comment: @Jubobs: I included a working example.
`\numberthis` does not work if it is not in an `align` environment.

Comment: @jubobs: interesting, but contains the ineffably clunky `\addtocounter{foo}{1}` rather than `\stepcounter{foo}` (or even `\refstepcounter{foo}` so that a label can be used).

Comment: @wasteofspace Thanks for your feedback. See the modified answer [there](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112478/21891).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `alignat*` environment is more suitable here than `align*` or an `array` (within a display-math environment). See below.

For numbering lines, you can use the command `\numberthis` which I define below. That command takes one optional argument, which if not empty, is used to create a label for cross-referencing. (Thanks to wasteofspace for his/her comments.)

Also, see [David Carlisle's recommendation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116841/21891) regarding the (ab)use of `\ensuremath`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand\numberthis[1][]{%
    \refstepcounter{equation}%
    \ifx#1\empty\else\label{eq:#1}\fi%
    \tag{\theequation}%
}

\newcommand*{\defeq}{\vcentcolon=}
\newcommand*{\diff}{\mathrm{d}}

\newcommand*{\pd}[3][]{%
    \frac{\partial^{#1}#2}{\partial #3^{#1}}
}

\newcommand*{\pdc}[4][]{%
    \left(\pd[#1]{#2}{#3}\right)_{\!\!#4}
}

\newcommand{\td}[3][]{%
    \frac{\diff^{#1}#2}{\diff #3^{#1}}
}

\newcommand{\earray}[3][2]{%
    \everymath{\displaystyle}%
    \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{#1}%
    \begin{array}{#2}
        #3
    \end{array}
}


\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{4}
        &\diff J^\pm 
            && \defeq \diff u\pm \frac{1}{C}\diff p 
            && =\left(F\pm\frac{1}{C}G\pdc{p}{e}{V}\right)\diff t 
            && \text{ along a path defined by } \td{\xi}{t}=\pm C,\\[1em]
        &\diff S
            && \defeq \diff p + C^2 \diff V
            && =G\pdc{p}{e}{V} \diff t 
            && \text{ along a path defined by } \td{\xi}{t}=0 \numberthis[ju]
\end{alignat*}
Equation \ref{eq:ju} is of interest for\ldots
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, `alignat` seems to be working pretty well. I was not aware of the right/left/right/left... alignment rule inside `align` environments.  
If I understand correctly, the big difference between `align` and `alignat` is that the latter does not expand the array to the whole page when there is more than one equation column. Is that correct ?
Also, while your answer is satisfying, I am still wondering whether or not it is possible to insert tags outside of environments such as `align`.

Comment: @zuggg -- `alignat` differs from `align` in that it doesn't add any horizontal space at all; that's up to the user.  it also requires that the number of column pairs be specified explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

Do not do this!

```
\newcommand*{\pd}[3][]{%
    \ensuremath%
    \frac{\partial^{#1}#2}{\partial #3^{#1}}
}
```

If used in math mode the `\ensuremath` does nothing but if used out of math mode it will expand to

```
$\relax\frac${\partial^{#1}#2}{\partial #3^{#1}}
```

and you will get lots of strange errors as `\frac` will not see its arguments and `\partial` will not be in math mode.

Just remove the `\ensuremath` line.

(for your actual question, I'd recommend using the AMS alignments as Jubobs suggests in his answer)